# <Code> tags CSS Like Wikipedia

Tags: html, css, mediawiki, wikipedia

I am coding some pages in HTML and CSS which will contain samples of code.  I want to have the grey box like the do on WikiPedia (I know this is done with Media Wiki). An example page is:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_(Unix)#Uses

You will see the code has a grey box with dotted lines around.  Also higher up the page where just 'dd' is used the text is monospace but no box is shown.

Could you tell me how I get the same styles with CSS around the  tag?

Thanks

Peter Jones

Comment: Here's an odd idea: look at the source... Or use the element inspector or some similar tool (firebug for example). You could've figured out the required CSS this way faster than creating a question here...

Answer (score 13):

**HTML**

```
<code>dd if=/dev/sda of=MBR.img bs=512 count=1</code>​
```

**CSS**

```
code{background:#F8F8FF; border:black dashed 1px; padding:6px}​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jk6wk/)**

Comment: -1: please teach him how to fish, instead of getting the fish for him and hooking it to his fishing rod.

Comment: There is only two properties of css so it can be easily understandable

Comment: You answer the question he asked, but his problem is that he doesn't know such a **basic** web development thing as "inspecting". He will have this same question over and over and over again: now it was with styling `code` tags; then it will be with adding borders under the titles; etc. We should teach the him how to inspect styles, instead of inspecting for him.

Comment: SO has an option called edit answer

Comment: My opinion is that editing it would significantly change its contents, so it would not be right to do and adding a new answer is instead the way to go. (@Sirko had one with this already, so I did not add a new one.)

Comment: Well your answer helped me for a simple solution, I appreciate it

Comment: code {
    border-left: 3px solid #f8cc6e;
    background-color: #e6e2d6;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: monospace;
    width: 96.5%;
    overflow: auto;
}

Answer (score 8):

Just use an any inspecting tool (like, e.g., Firebug) to see, what CSS has been used on a page. As for your example, this is the following:

```
{
    background-color: #F9F9F9;
    border: 1px dashed #2F6FAB;
    color: black;
    line-height: 1.1em;
    padding: 1em;
}
```

PS: If you want to have code highlighting, have a look at [highlight.js](http://softwaremaniacs.org/soft/highlight/en/).

Comment: +1 suggesting firebug-like tool

Answer (score 0):

```
div {
    width:500px;
    background-color:#F9F9F9;
    padding:20px 20px;
    border:1px dashed blue;
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/naWLM/1/

If I understood correctly this is what you wanted.

Comment: -1: that styles all divs. You should either limit it by adding a class to the selector, or change the selector to apply to code tags, or something similar.

Comment: Yes that is commun sense, it was only for the example.